# lambda calculus in scala

Tags: scala, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

OK, so I'm trying to implement the [basics of lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). Here it goes.

My numbers:

```
def zero[Z](s: Z => Z)(z: Z): Z = z
def one[Z](s: Z => Z)(z: Z): Z = s(z)
def two[Z](s: Z => Z)(z: Z): Z = s(s(z))
```

Partially (actually, non) applied version of them is smth like that:

```
def z[Z]: (Z => Z) => (Z => Z) = zero _
```

Before I continue I define some types:

```
type FZ[Z] = Z => Z
type FFZ[Z] = FZ[Z] => FZ[Z]
```

Fine, `succ` function goes like (Application order should be *exactly* like that! I took the definition [here](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf)):

```
def succ[Z](w: FFZ[Z])(y: FZ[Z])(x: Z): Z = y((w(y))(x))
```

And the unapplied version of it gets as scary as:

```
def s[Z]: FFFZ[Z] = successor _
```

Beg your pardon, here is the missing types:

```
type FFFZ[Z] = FFZ[Z] => FFZ[Z]
type FFFFZ[Z] = FFFZ[Z] => FFFZ[Z]
```

But I'm stuck at the `add` function. If conformed to types and definition (taken [here](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf) as well) it goes like

```
def add[Z](a: FFFFZ[Z])(b: FFZ[Z]): FFZ[Z] =
  (a(s))(b)
```

But I want `a` to be a common number of type `FFZ[Z]`.

So -- how can I define addition?

Comment: My first guess was that it works only for untyped lambda calculus, where value is just *somehting* and function is a mapping from *something* to *something* so I can invoke function `f` whose argument type is, say, `a: Z -> Z` and it might not not exactly conform to a function `f': (Z -> Z) -> (Z -> Z)` I apply it to.

Comment: Perhaps a title like "Addition for Church numerals in Scala" would be a bit more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's totally possible to implement Church numerals in Scala. Here is one such rather straight-forward implementation:

```
object ChurchNumerals {

  type Succ[Z] = Z => Z
  type ChNum[Z] = Succ[Z] => Z => Z

  def zero[Z]: ChNum[Z] =
    (_: Succ[Z]) => (z: Z) => z

  def succ[Z] (num: ChNum[Z]): ChNum[Z] =
    (s: Succ[Z]) => (z: Z) => s( num(s)(z) )

  // a couple of church constants
  def one[Z] : ChNum[Z] = succ(zero)
  def two[Z] : ChNum[Z] = succ(one)

  // the addition function
  def add[Z] (a: ChNum[Z]) (b: ChNum[Z]) =
    (s: Succ[Z]) => (z: Z) => a(s)( b(s)(z) )

  def four[Z] : ChNum[Z] = add(two)(two)

  // test
  def church_to_int (num: ChNum[Int]): Int =
    num((x: Int) => x + 1)(0)

  def fourInt: Int = church_to_int(four)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(s"2 + 2 = ${fourInt}")
  }
}
```

Compiles and prints:

```
$ scala church-numerals.scala
2 + 2 = 4
```

If I were to explain Church numerals from scratch I'd add more commentaries. But taking the context into account, I'm not sure on what to comment in this case. Please feel free to ask and I'll add more explanations.

Comment: That's beautiful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have coded Numerals, Booleans and Pairs: https://github.com/pedrofurla/church/blob/master/src/main/scala/Church.scala following Church's style.

One thing I noticed is that using the curried function syntax was much easier than using multiple argument lists. Some of the interesting snippets

```
type NUM[A] = (A => A) => A => A
def succ  [A]: NUM[A]  =>  NUM[A] = m => n => x => n(m(n)(x))
def zero  [A]: NUM[A] = f => x => x
def one   [A]: NUM[A] = f => x => f(x)
def two   [A]: NUM[A] = f => x => f(f(x))
def three [A]: NUM[A] = f => x => f(f(f(x)))
def plus  [A]: (NUM[A]) => (NUM[A]) => NUM[A] = m => n => f => x => m(f)(n(f)(x))
```

Now for printing them out (very similar to Antov Trunov's solution):

```
def nvalues[A] = List(zero[A], one[A], two[A], three[A])

val inc: Int => Int  = _ + 1 
def num: (NUM[Int]) => Int = n => n(inc)(0)
def numStr: (NUM[String]) => String = n => n("f (" + _ + ") ")("z")
```

Some output:

```
scala> println(nvalues map num)
List(0, 1, 2, 3)

scala> println(nvalues map numStr) // Like this better :)
List(z, f (z) , f (f (z) ) , f (f (f (z) ) ) )
```